# Weird behavior about numpy.mean()

Tags: numpy

I am using numpy 1.21.

```
import numpy as np

a = [(1, 1), (2,)]
np.mean(a)
```

It returns:

array([0.5, 0.5, 1. ])

It's not the mean of flattened array. Can anyone understand why it got returned?

Comment: I think this works roughly as follows: if you run np.array(a).sum() you get `(1, 1, 2)` (since tuple addition is concatenation). The result then seems to be divided by the number of elements in `a` and returned as numpy array.

Comment: If you are using a recent version of numpy, you should have gotten a warning: `VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.`

Comment: Use `np.mean(np.hstack(a))` if you want the mean of the flattened array.  In other words, flatten it first.   If you don't understand what `np.array(a)` produces, your expectations will be unreliable.

Comment: @hpaulj. `np.concatenate(a)` would be cleaner, no?